# How to create time series based on sequence of time stamps using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, time-series

[image]

Here is what i try to do: 
I have machine states on a time stamp basis. I wannt to define start and end Timestamp by creating 1 row. So, the result should show the beginning of machine state 1 and the end time stamp. Next row should display the duration (start timestamp = end time stamp previous series) for machine state 0 having reason ID 15 . Who can help out?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using tSQL